# Multiple connection strings using redis-py

Tags: python, redis, high-availability, redis-py

I'm trying to configure multiple connection strings for a single `ConnectionPool` in `redis-py`. Our Redis nodes are sitting behind a reverse proxy (let's say NGINX), of which we have multiple for increased redundancy. The idea is to initialize the `ConnectionPool` in `redis-py` with a list of all the URLs in case one goes down. Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

multi-master connections are not possible in `redis-py` nor in any other Redis client, I'm aware of. You would have to implement this on your own.

A workaround could be to use DNS load balancing: https://www.nginx.com/resources/glossary/dns-load-balancing

Regards, Martin